# Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Tags: java, arrays

How to fix this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

When I try to run this program I get this error message.
Really stuck in this program

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String firstLine = (args[0]);
    String secondLine = (args[1]);
    String thirdLine = (args[2]);
    int LinesBefore = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    int LinesAfter = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
    int Spaces = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
    if (args.length == 1 || args.length == 2 || args.length == 5 || args.length > 6)
    {
        Open open = new Open();
        System.out.println("Error: Incorrect numbers of parameter.");
        System.out.println("Program now terminating.");
    }
    else if(args.length == 3)
    {
        Open open = new Open(firstLine,secondLine,thirdLine);
        open.display();
    }
    else if(args.length == 4)
    {
        Open open= new Open(firstLine,secondLine,thirdLine,LinesBefore);
        open.display();
    }
    else if(args.length == 6)
    {
        Open open = new Open(firstLine,secondLine,thirdLine,LinesBefore,LinesAfter,Spaces);
        open.display();        }
    else if(args.length == 0)
    {
        Open open = new Open();
        open.display();        }
}
```

Comment: You checked the length after you attempted to access an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `args[0]` if `args.length > 0` and so on.

I would suggest moving access to `args` inside the condition instead of before `args.length` check. E.g.

```
else if(args.length == 3)
{
   String firstLine = (args[0]);
   String secondLine = (args[1]);
   String thirdLine = (args[2]);

   Open open = new Open(firstLine,secondLine,thirdLine);
   open.display();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your error is here:**

```
String firstLine = (args[0]);
String secondLine = (args[1]);
String thirdLine = (args[2]);
int LinesBefore = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
int LinesAfter = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
int Spaces = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
```

*You're trying to access an element in array that maybe don't exist, depending on how many parameters you specified when running.*

**One of possible solutions:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if (args.length == 1 || args.length == 2 || args.length == 5 || args.length > 6)
    {
        Open open = new Open();
        System.out.println("Error: Incorrect numbers of parameter.");
        System.out.println("Program now terminating.");
    }
    else if(args.length == 3)
    {
        Open open = new Open(args[0],args[1],args[2]);
        open.display();
    }
    else if(args.length == 4)
    {
        Open open= new Open(args[0],args[1],args[2],Integer.parseInt(args[3]));
        open.display();
    }
    else if(args.length == 6)
    {
        Open open = new Open(args[0],args[1],args[2],Integer.parseInt(args[3]),Integer.parseInt(args[4]),Integer.parseInt(args[5]));
        open.display();        }
    else if(args.length == 0)
    {
        Open open = new Open();
        open.display();        }
}
```

Comment: The elements of an array are now accessed only if they exist. You technically can't get the same error. Have you tried exactly what I've written?

Answer (score 0):

```
String firstLine = (args[0]);
String secondLine = (args[1]);
String thirdLine = (args[2]);
int LinesBefore = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
int LinesAfter = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
int Spaces = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
```

For that to work `args.length` must be at least 6, otherwise you can't access all of the Array indices up to 5. To avoid such an exception you must first check `args.length` and then never access indices greater than `array.length - 1`